# Crop a Square Image of 450x450 into 9 pieces of 150x150 each, using PHP

Tags: php, imagecreatefrompng

I have an source image of 450x450 px. And i want to crop it into 9 peices of 150x150 each using PHP.
I am using the following code.
I am getting 9 images, but cropping is not appropriate.
Here is the screen shot :
[image]
Last one is the source image i am using.
Here is my Code.

```
<?php

$targ_w = $targ_h = 150;
$jpeg_quality = 25;

$src = "puzzleimages/puzzle2.jpg";

$y = 0;
$y2 = 150;
$x = 0;
$x2 = 150;

$i = 3;
$name = 0;
while( $i-- ){
    $j = 3;

    while( $j-- ){


        $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
        $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

        imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$x,$y,$targ_w,$targ_h,$x2,$y2);

        //header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($dst_r,'puzzleimages/'.++$name.'.jpg', $jpeg_quality);

        $x += 150;
        $x2 += 150;

    }


    $y += 150;
    $y2 += 150;
    $x = 0;
    $x2 = 150;

}

?>
```

Can anyone suggest what is going wrong?

Comment: `exec(sprintf("convert -crop 150x150 %s", escapeshellarg($fn)))` would be the simpler alternative for generating tiles.

Comment: I have done something very similar in imagemagick, do you have that library avail?

Comment: I have never used any external library, so i am avoiding imagemagick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to keep changing the source width/height, and it should be 150 all the time.  Give this a try:

```
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$x,$y,$targ_w,$targ_h,$targ_w,$targ_h);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool imagecopyresampled ( resource $dst_image , resource $src_image , int $dst_x , int$dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $dst_w , int $dst_h , int $src_w , int $src_h )
```

Refer to Php documentation, the only parameters need to be changed are `src_x` and `src_y`. Since you changed your `x2` and `y2`, the following will be applied:

> If the source and destination coordinates and width and heights differ, appropriate stretching or shrinking of the image fragment will be performed.